# Is there a term for "manga language"?

Tags: meaning, words

The language used in manga often does not follow standard patterns. Is there a term for this? Thank you.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine what type of "language" you have in mind. Can you give us a few examples which you think are typycally specific to manga?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer would probably disappoint you if you were expecting  a short concrete term as an answer such as 「〇〇[語]{ご}」 or 「〇〇[言葉]{ことば}」.   Frankly, I doubt that such a (short) term exists that would be universally understood.

The kind of language spoken by manga characters vastly differ from one manga title to the next.  Characters speak just like "regular" native speakers from real life in some manga titles, and characters speak nowhere near like real people in others.  The point is that **among the latter group, a countless number of speech patterns can be found**.

Thus, I could only come up with "explanatory phrases" rather than common terms as;

「マンガで（よく）見{み}る / 聞{き}くような言葉 / 言葉[遣]{づか}い / 表現{ひょうげん}」

「マンガ的{てき}な / マンガみたいな / マンガっぽい言葉 / 言葉遣い / 表現」

Any of those word combinations will be understood by native speakers with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a term for this but you can use タメ語 although its scope is much broader than just patterns you find in manga. Actually it's more about everything that is not considered as polite.

If you want to play it safe (ie. be sure to be understood) and not use a one-word expression, you can also use 漫画の言葉, 漫画に出てくる言葉 or 漫画の言葉遣い.

Comment: I can't vouch for the naturalness of the expressions I gave you but they will for sure be understood as "manga language" (except maybe だめ語 because it is a bit vague).

Comment: I have not seen ダメ語. Do you mean タメ語? (Although it's not related to "manga language")

Comment: @Naruto Yes, I meant タメ語. I may not have insisted enough on the fact that it means more rough language than precisely "manga language" which is why I provided the other expressions.

Answer (score 1):

漫画のセリフ would be natural when you mention one specific reference among many of them. Because not all the manga scripts are eccentric. Some are not following the standard by the purposes, such as character making and taste or constructions of the story.

Term is translated into 用語

It's useful for the most of cases, e.g. アニメ用語 (Terms for Anime) 囲碁用語 (Terms for IGO) ゲーム用語 (Terms for games) コンピューター用語 (Terms for computers)

漫画用語 is not useful most of the time. An older generation merely got it.  This is an exception, it could be gotten the terms used by  the manga composers, not for the language in manga.

Comment: 「漫画用語」はsometimesじゃなくてほぼ確実に「ネーム」や「ベタ」や「トーン」のことなのでは…

Comment: naruto's suggestion is correct, only older generation 60+ y.o. would say that.